# Can I use a client online payment portal with iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, credit-card

This is higher level question and I'm mainly concerned about the rules surrounding attempting to do this.

I'm building an app to allow for buying from a store and am considering using one of several payment solutions (the current leader being stripe).  The store already has an online payment portal with lower card fees.  Could I possibly store the users card info in app and make a secure connection to their online portal to take advantage of the lower card fees?  I found this question that seems to indicate yes, but its a very old question and not sure if it still holds up.  Or is there some value in the stripe system I am missing?

[Is it allowed to ask users to enter credit card details for own payment method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621223/is-it-allowed-to-ask-users-to-enter-credit-card-details-for-own-payment-method)

Comment: Afaik if you are selling physical good or services delivered outside the app you cns use any payment method you like.

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not be able to use Stripe in-app, depending on what you're selling: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-vs-in-app-purchases

Comment: How does stripe in-app help in regards to fees?  The online store runs somewhere are 2-2.5% while stripe is 2.9 + 30c.

Comment: I've looked at your link again and reread your answer, it appears you are simply informing that stripe is an option but as I stated in my question I already know this but the fees are relatively high.  I am asking about for specific functionality I may be missing or insight into integrating with existing online portals.